# Reading file using fscanf in C

Tags: file-io, scanf

I have a fixed format text file to be read in my C program.
The format of the text file is as below:

```
w 400341a0
r dfcfa8
w 7b034dd4
```

The first character is always w or r, while the second element is a 32bit hex digit.

I have written the code as below to read this file line by line :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* file_ptr;
    char rw;
    uint32_t address;
    int file_read;
    uint32_t file_line_ctr = 1;

    #if(MODE == DEBUG)
    {
         printf("DEBUG_MODE\n ");
    }
    #else
    {
        /*Do Nothing*/
    }
    #endif



    file_ptr = fopen(argv[10], "r");

    if (file_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't Open File\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File Opened Successfully\n");
    }

    file_read = fscanf(file_ptr, "%c %x" , &rw, &address);
    printf("%c %x \n", rw, address);

    while (file_read!= EOF)
    {
      file_read = fscanf(file_ptr, "%c %x" , &rw, &address); 
      file_line_ctr ++;  
      printf("%c %x \n", rw, address);
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);

    printf("File Length = %d \n", file_line_ctr);

    return 1;
}
```

I get the output in the below format for a file with 100000 entries:

```
w 400341a0 

 400341a0 
r dfcfa8 

 dfcfa8 
w 7b034dd4 

 7b034dd4

 File Length = 200000
```

Evidently, I am reading the entries twice for some reason, as well as printing them twice.
Can someone figure out why is it so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Here is a fix

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* file_ptr;
    char rw;
    unsigned int address;
    int file_read=0;
    unsigned int file_line_ctr = 1;

    #if(MODE == DEBUG)
    {
         printf("DEBUG_MODE\n ");
    }
    #else
    {
        /*Do Nothing*/
    }
    #endif



    file_ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't Open File\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File Opened Successfully\n");
    }
/*

    file_read = fscanf(file_ptr, "%c %x " , &rw, &address);
    printf("%c %x \n", rw, address);
*/
    while (true)
    {
      file_read = fscanf(file_ptr, "%c %x " , &rw, &address); 
      if (file_read == EOF)
    break; 
      file_line_ctr ++;  
      printf("%c %x \n", rw, address);
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);

    printf("File Length = %d \n", file_line_ctr);

    return 1;
}
```

You will notice that I have added a space after the %x to eat the newlines as white space.
I have also modified your while loop a little to stop the last line being repeat printed. Crude. But it will work until you can rethink the logic. The while (true) may not work with all compilers. I used while (1). Which is non standard but worked for me.